# jfrog artifactory after 6.2.0 upgrade using get [RELEASE] no longer works?

Tags: artifactory

After upgrading to Artifactory Pro 6.2.0 using [RELEASE] for the version in the requested path to get the latest Maven release artifact no longer seems to work.

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate -N --user=reader --password=****** -P . https://artifactory.***.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/envision/tools/envision-buildtools/\[RELEASE\]/envision-buildtools-\[RELEASE\].tgz
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2018-08-14 10:45:59--  https://artifactory.****.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/envision/tools/envision-buildtools/[RELEASE]/envision-buildtools-[RELEASE].tgz
Resolving artifactory.***.com... 10.***.**.**
Connecting to artifactory.***.com|10.***.**.**|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2018-08-14 10:45:59 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Is there any work-around or fix for this?

Comment: formatting needs to be addressed in this question.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was a Tomcat issue - not an Artifactory bug. We had to update the server.xml to add the relaxedPathChars and relaxedQueryChars attributes as shown below.

```
<Connector port="8081" sendReasonPhrase="true" relaxedPathChars='[]' relaxedQueryChars='[]'/>
```